# Activity display overlaps Fragment on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, device-orientation

I am making an app that changes between fragments and activities using a navigation drawer.

I can switch between the activity(which contains an empty view or recyclerview) and fragments using the navigation drawer but when I change the orientation when the fragment is loaded and activity hidden from view (empty view or recyclerview), the activity layout will overlap the fragment when it is restored after the orientation change. The emptyview/recyclerview are no longer hidden. What I would like is for the fragment remain loaded and the activity layout to remain hidden after the orientation change. I've tried  `if (savedInstanceState == null)` but that didn't work.

Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated to help solve this issue.

```
     public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    
     LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, 
      NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,DefinitionFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,WeatherFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,PlanetFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private static final int ASTRONOMY_LOADER = 0;
    private CustomCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    ViewGroup emptyView;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private static final  String TAG = "Fragment";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState == null){
                fab.hide();
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }

            fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));


            //Setup an Adapter to create the recycler items for each row of prescription data in the Cursor.
            //There is no prescription data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor.
            mAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            //Kick off the loader
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(ASTRONOMY_LOADER, null, this);




        }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to a click on the "Delete all entries" menu option
            case R.id.action_delete_all_entries:
                deleteAllCalculations();
                return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

     @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.astronomyCalculations) {
            if(fragment!=null) {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout));
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                fab.show();
                if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }

        } else if (id == R.id.definition) {
            // Handle the definition fragment
            fragment = new DefinitionFragment();
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                fab.hide();
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. All I had to do was go into androidmanifest and add:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden
```

in the activity section. It prevents the activity from restarting which is what I wanted.